# How to put all zeros in a integer to the right without external storage

Tags: algorithm, math

How can we shift all the zeros in an integer to the right.

For example, int x = 560106 , after shifting, x = 561600.

We cannot use another variable and String manipulation is not a good answer.

Also, I do know the dirty method of using mod recursively depending upon the integer length.

Comment: Clearly (?) it can't be done as "bit-manipulation", since the question in posed in terms of powers of 10. And I'm pretty sure that you need either recursion or else another variable to hold the power of ten you're currently working on. I may be wrong, and I suppose that for a known size of `int` you could unroll that loop anyway.

Comment: @Steve: As mentioned, we cannot have another variable. I have a solution for integer with unknown length and using mod recursively. But this is a dirty method. There have to be a simpler way.

Comment: Could you expand upon "cannot use another variable"? Are you saying that the only declarations allowed in our program are 'int main()' and 'int x' ?

Comment: @Rob: we cannot store any new information like if you want to store positions of zeros or length of the integer. Also, its a brain teaser so we are more worried about the logic and not the program. But answering your question, YES. only main() and int x.

Comment: @Wipqozn: it was an interview question. and i am curious to know the answer. i have one solution but looking for alternative.

Comment: Don't keep us in suspense, post the answer you have.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is your solution, but a recursive implementation is (sorry about using Scheme - I dabble in it, so I try to use it for practice):

```
(define (bubble-digit-up number digit)
  (if (= number 0)
      digit
    (let ((last-digit (modulo number 10)))
      (if (= last-digit 0)
          (* (bubble-digit-up (/ number 10) digit) 10)
        (+ (* number 10) digit)))))

(define (shift-zeros-right x)
  (if (<= x 0)
      0
    (let* ((last-digit (modulo x 10))
           (rest (shift-zeros-right (/ (- x last-digit) 10))))
      (bubble-digit-up rest last-digit))))
```

The function `bubble-digit-up` gets two parameters: a number, and a digit. It moves the digit near the first nonzero digit. For example, `(bubble-digit-up 100 4)` will return `1400`. `shift-zeros-right` is the main function, which solves the problem recursively: extract first digit, shift the zeros of the remainder to right, and bubble the extracted digit into place.

Not a very elegant implementation, and definitely not bit operations (as per the tag), but this is the best I've got so far.

---

EDIT: If you consider the use of `let` as cheating, here is the variable-less version:

```
(define (bubble-digit-up number digit)
  (if (= number 0)
      digit
    (if (= (modulo number 10) 0)
        (* (bubble-digit-up (/ number 10) digit) 10)
      (+ (* number 10) digit))))

(define (shift-zeros x)
  (if (<= x 0)
      0
    (bubble-digit-up 
     (shift-zeros (/ (- x (modulo x 10)) 10))
     (modulo x 10))))
```

---

EDIT2: A Python implementation may be easier to follow:

```
def bubble_digit_up(num, digit):
    if num == 0:
        return digit
    else:
        if num%10 == 0:
            return 10*bubble_digit_up(num/10, digit)
        else:
            return 10*num + digit

def shift_zeros_right(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return bubble_digit_up(shift_zeros_right(x/10), x%10)
```

Comment: Finally somebody started giving answers instead of incrementing/decrementing persons reputation...let me go through this...Thanks...

Comment: No worries. It was interesting to work with. :) Another possible solution is `remove_zero_digits(num)*(10**count_zero_digits(num))`, where the two functions can be coded up recursively too. I guess the aim of the question was to see if you can do recursive functions - as it is an obvious method to hide variable usage. :)

Comment: Yes the aim is to find an efficient way to get the answer i.e. all zeroes to right and rest on left.